# BibTex error using Texmaker and Jabref

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker, jabref

I'm writing a paper that has citations in it. I use Jabref to organize the citations.

Where I run Texmaker I get the following error:

[image]

What weird is that when I run this on a different computer, everything works fine (so I assume that my .bib file is ok).

Is there any solution for this? Saw few questions about this subject however without any answer.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` (the package), then you probably need to run Biber instead of BibTeX on your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Im using \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}, and when I run the code it uses: PdfLaTex + BibTex + PdfLatex x2. How can I control to make i Biber and not BibTex?

Comment: Yes, then you need to run Biber and not BibTeX (the link in my comment above tells you how to do that). For future questions, please always include a short example document that shows the bits of code relevant to the question (in this case what bibliography and citation packages you load and how you cite). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: It worked mate, thank you very much.